# Applying functional extensionality to functions with 2 arguments in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove something like this:

```
(fun (i : nat) (ic : i < S n) => ...) = (fun (i : nat) (ip : i < S n) => ...)
```

It sounds like a task for `apply functional_extensionality` but it fails to unify. I suspect I need to somehow to apply it twice but unsure how to do this.

Comment: The problem is not that you need to apply it twice, it is that the second argument is type-dependent on the first one. So you should apply the dependent version `functional_extensionality_dep` (which is done by the tactic `extensionality`). Moreover, if the function bodies are identical, you can use directly `reflexivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself :)

```
  extensionality a.
  extensionality b.
```